# What is a good filament for a frame for holding high amp copper busbar?

Tags: filament, electronics, filament-choice, filament-quality

I need a frame to hold a copper busbar in place.  The busbar is rated up to 200 amps and can be wrapped in an insulator, so the frame will sit around the insulator of the busbar, but I don't know how hot it gets.

I would like to 3D print a frame to hold the busbar in place, what is the most suitable filament for this application?

Comment: Without knowing how hot the busbar gets, or a vague temperature range required, it *might* be difficult to suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would use ABS, but you shouldn't rely on the filament. This is a job for insulation to take care of. You don't expect the holder to do any more than hold the component in electrical applications.